# How to make sure that Google indexes your site in less than a day?

Tags: search, google, seo, web-crawlers, googlebot

I am thinking of creating a website where the content will be only useful for a max of one week. I am also assuming that I will be getting most of the traffic thru search engines basically Google. For important sites like stackoverflow the crawling happens multiple times a day. But for a new site with time-dependent content, is it possible to get Google to index the site more frequently.

Comment: please see this answer to understand what "indexing" means (and that there are a lot of dependencies) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537612/pages-not-indexed-by-google/5548511#5548511

Answer (score 5):

Use google sitemaps.  We use them where I work, you can specify how often pages change, etc:

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184&from=40318&rd=1

You cannot guarantee that they will crawl today, but for a small enough site, it will help them find your content faster.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I am not so sure that you could get search engines like Google index your web site in less than a day just simply adding a sitemap or even ping the sitemap to other sites. Various source shows that creating a sitemap or submitting a sitemap to search engines can not guarantee anything.I have not done that before though. My advise about sitemap is do it, but do not expect too much, especially regarding to get indexed quickly or get a higher ranking.

As you noticed, StackOverflow is doing exceptionally well both in terms of craw frequency and ranking. One of the biggest strengths of it is it provides **unique**, **valuable** and **fresh** content. As the cliche goes, content is king, if you want to lure search engines to visit your web site and index your content, you need to provide something that grab their attention, that is, I tell you, content, fresh, unique content.

In addition to that, link building is a very important part in search engine optimization(SEO). Links from good sites, meaning sharing same content or famous sites like NYTIMES, will give your more leverage in terms of indexing frequency and ranking.

Then we come to tech area, good code, semantic html is also important.Tags like `h`, `strong` `head`

,`description` are important.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a sitemap, then use some code like this (example is in PHP), to ping the sitemap to the major search engines.

```
function ping_sitemap($sitemap_url) {
    $pingurls = array(
        "http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=",
        "http://submissions.ask.com/ping?sitemap=",
        "http://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap="
    );

    foreach ($pingurls as $pingurl) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $pingurl.$sitemap_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }   
}
```

$sitemap_url needs to be the whole URL, starting with http://, not a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a site like Linklicious.me that creates feeds from links then pings Google until the link(s) get crawled. That and the sitemap will improve the speed, but can still take several days. I would set up the site now and submit the sitemap, so when the time comes to add your new content at least the site has already been indexed. Additionally, blasting your content through Twitter, Facebook, Flickr, YouTube, etc. as well as discussion forums will help things get picked up faster.

Answer (score 0):

I've had websites indexed very quickly when promoted using a Twitter account. It is worth mentioning that the account has been created before the website went online, had lots of followers and followed a certain number of Twitter users, was highly customized and tweeted interesting, non-spam content.
This is the fastest method I know, but I don't think it can guarantee indexing in under a day.